# Array of a type with different types inside

Tags: arduino-c++

I'm creating an Array of a Class Type (*Button*), and I want to have a subclass of it called *ButtonMb* inside the array *Button*
Is that possible?
I tried to have two different constructors and use only one Class, but since number of parameters are the same, I couln't reach anywhere.

Here is my code:
**for simplicity I only included header code for class declaration**

```cpp
typedef void (*Callback)(void);
typedef int (*CallbackInt)(void);

class Button {
  public:
    OneButton _pin;

    Button(uint8_t pin, Callback click=NULL, Callback longCl=NULL, Callback dblCl=NULL);
  
    void loop();
};

class ButtonMb : public Button {
  public:
    CallbackInt _pinState;

    ButtonMb(CallbackInt pinState, Callback click=NULL, Callback longCl=NULL, Callback dblCl=NULL);
    
    void loop();
};

Button buttons[2] = {
  Button(14),
  ButtonMb([](){return slaves[0].getState("A15");)
};
```

Any help?

NOTE: I'm using Arduino, so code can be limited.

Comment: Nope, sorry, arrays in C++ don't work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using array of objects, you can create array of pointers. Pointers of base class can point to derived classes, so you can have pointers to objects of different types in one array.

Comment: like this? `Button* buttons[2]={Button(14), ButtonMb(...)};`

Comment: Close, it would be better if you first allocated those buttons on heap, now you tried to insert objects instead of pointers pointing to the objects.
Button* b_ptr = new Button(14);
Button* mb_ptr = new ButtonMb(...);
Button* buttons[2]={b_ptr, mb_ptr);

Comment: There may be no need for dynamic allocation. For example, `Button button(14); ButtonMb buttonmb(...); Button* buttons[]={&button, &buttonmb};`. If you find yourself needing dynamic allocation, consider using a smart pointer to manage the allocation: `std::unique_ptr<Button> buttons[]={std::make_unique<Button>(14), std::make_unique<ButtonMb>(...)};`. [documentation for `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [documentation for `std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).